# Ошибка доступа чтения/записи по FTP

Tags: python, ftp

Собственно, код:

```
import ftplib
import ftputil

class FTPSession(ftplib.FTP):
    def __init__(self, addr, user, passw, port):
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self)
        self.connect(addr, port)
        self.login(user, passw)
        self.set_pasv(False)

class FastFTP:
    def __init__(self, addr, port, user, passw):
        self.ftpCl = ftputil.FTPHost(addr, user, passw, port=port, session_factory=FTPSession)
    def upload(self, source, target = 0, mode = " "):
        if not target:
            target = os.path.split(source)[1]
        return self.ftpCl.upload(source, target, mode)


x = FastFTP("addr", 21, "login", "passw")
print x.upload("./a.zip", "a.zip")
```

Возникает ошибка:

> ftputil.ftp_error.FTPIOError: 500 I won't open a connection to 0.0.0.0 (only to [мой ip])

Как лечить? Не предлагайте пассивный режим и настройку файерволов.

Comment: Очень интересно. Что это за таинственный сервер "addr", который даёт Вам ошибку 500, и где он находится?

Comment: это пример.

Comment: Так, продолжаем сеанс телепатии. Сервер на вашем компутере, или где-то вдали? Что за сервер?

Comment: Спрашивай всё сразу. Это удалённый FTP-сервер, с ним спокойно работает FileZilla, но вот в питоне я не могу реализовать нормальную работу. Включил дебаг, в консоли видно, что зависает на "Accepted data connection"

Comment: У меня ваш скрипт (без последней строки -- upload) нормально отрабатывает для ftp.ru, анонимный пользователь, т.е. нормально логинится.

Comment: Вся проблема в upload. Подключение установить удаётся, а что-то сделать не выходит. Пробовал посылать команды, тоже нет ответа.

Comment: А у этих модулей ftplib/ftputil есть журналы? Да ладно, х. с ними, что говорит товарищ Сниффер?